# Can not load external script js file wtih spring

Tags: javascript, java, spring, vue.js

Structure is:

src
-main
    --resources
    ---vue.html
    ---example.js

vue.html is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
<!--    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>-->
    <script src="./example.js"></script>

    <script>
        alert("I'm active");


    </script>
```

this is working for the alert : **I'm active**

but **404** for

http://localhost:8080/example.js

but for, it gives error. SAme error.

By the way, the endpoind is that:

```
@GetMapping("/vue")
public ModelAndView getAllvue() {

    return new ModelAndView("vue");
}
```

I go to http://localhost:8080/vue but I cant go to

http://localhost:8080/vue.js

It gives

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
```

But in intellj idea, when i right click html and say **open in browser**, it goes to

http://localhost:63343/myproject/templates/vue.html?_ijt=v7rpc3a98pdc66ml94fp8iikn

and my script works. This is `**example.js**`

```
alert("This script will load first");
```

So, what is blocking my js to work?

This is security config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
//@EnableWebMvc
public class WebSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    String[] resources = new String[]{
            "/",
            "/home",
            "/css/**",
            "/icons/**",
            "/images/**",
            "/resources/**",
            "/static/**",
            "/js/**"
    };

  http.csrf().disable();

    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(resources).permitAll()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/authenticateTheUser")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/dashboard")
            .permitAll();
}
```

I also tried with those:

```
<script src="./example.js"></script>
<script src="../example.js"></script>
<script src="/example.js"></script>
<script src="templates/example.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code to load static files.

```
@Configuration
//@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry
            .addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
            .addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        String[] resources = new String[]{
            "/",
                "/home",
                "/css/**",
                "/icons/**",
                "/images/**",
                "/resources/**",
                "/static/**",
                "/js/**"
        };
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(resources).permitAll()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/authenticateTheUser")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/dashboard")
            .permitAll();
    }
}
```

And call it in your html page like .

```
<script src="http://localhost:8080/myproject/resources/vau.js"></script>
```

Hope this will solve the issue.

Comment: But `@EnableWebMvc` disables MVC autoconfiguration ?

Comment: You can use without this as the spring will add this automatically .

Comment: Also it gives `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'` for `    <link href="<c:url value="/resources/templates/vue.js"/>" rel="stylesheet">`

Comment: Sorry change the path with the full path, I have updated the answer

Comment: But i need `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` because I do `ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider` and http://localhost:63343 is not my URL. My url's port is 8080

Comment: You can keep that as well, this is for static resources.

Comment: But if i do `implements WebMvcConfigurer`, i lost `extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter `

Comment: I have updated the code, you can extend and implement both

Comment: It shows `" rel="stylesheet">` on screen. I think it needed to be escaped

Comment: Sorry , replace `link` tag with script , we are loading js so it should be `script`, updated the code.

Comment: It does not work still , probably because of i cant go to http://localhost:8080/vue.js or  http://localhost:8080/myproject/main/resources/templates/vue.js my port is 8080.